# Optimize this double left join query?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm modifying my original query which is just pulling reservations from the **bookings** table to join to a table of **units** which joins to a table of **buildings** in order to retrieve the building names and unit id for each booking.

I have created a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7d74e1/4) for this with the explain prefixed to the query. Per @Alex, I added an index on `bookings.unit_number` which in the SQLFiddle is `bookings.external_system_id`. ( Ignore the secondary field ).

This is still taking some time ( minutes ) when I do a full export for all bookings. I'm just trying to optimize this as best I can as I realize a full export will still take awhile ( total of 13019077 results ).

Comment: why do you `join` if you are not using any column from `units` ?

Comment: By the way, I prefixed the SELECT with EXPLAIN but it's not making total sense to me.

Comment: @vkp - added the final query which extracts data from the buildings table.

Comment: I don't really know mysql, but make sure you've got indexes on `buildings.id`, `units.id`, `units.unit_number` and `bookings.unit_number`. Also, the result set of 13 million records seems like there is an issue with the join. I'd make sure you're not accidentally doing something like `... ON units.unit_number = units.unit_number` (that's burned me in the past)

Comment: Use inner join hope it will work.

Comment: Add an index on bookings.unit_number. I can't say for sure without seeing the query plan, but it is most likely doing a full table scan to join.

Comment: are there 2 columns `unit_number` and `unitnumber` in the `bookings` table?

Comment: Please add the table and index definitions and the output from `explain select ...`

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong. So Unit table has 2 columns unit_number and id. This id is used to join building. So any unit.id which would come as null from first join, is not needed for joining building. So you should join normal join for unit and then left outer for building. Can you try and see if you get same output?

Comment: Since Units would be a parent table to Bookings, A left join would be wrong unless you have a serious data integrity problem. You shouldn't be able to book a unit that doesn't exist in the Units table. You need to understand the meaning of your data model and there is no way that a left join makes sense in this case. Same with building, you can't have a a booking unless there is a building involved.

Comment: @Alex - adjusted with an index but it's still taking some time for a full report query. Any further optimizations I can do?

Comment: @HLGEM - are you suggesting an INNER JOIN? this is for reporting purposes.

Comment: @meder I think the answer from Ollie Jones covers my initial thoughts. The only other advice I can offer is to look at the query plan to actually understand what is taking the time. Watch out for scalar-functions too.

Comment: Why would reporting purposes make it an outer join? Yes, I think that you need inner joins because from a data meaning perspective that is the only thin that makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're dealing with a complex aspect of SQL. You might want to read http://use-the-index-luke.com

With respect, your statement

> There are filters for date range and property but these are optional

is likely to make any advice you get from us entirely worthless unless you show us what those filters look like. But, still, I'll try to help.

Create compound [covering indexes](http://planet.mysql.com/entry/?id=661727) on `units (unit_number, id)` and `buildings(id,name)` and see if performance improves.  These compound indexes should help performance.  If you're filtering on `bookings.arrival` then you might also create a compound index on `bookings (arrival, unit_number)` for the same purpose.

**In InnoDB** there's no point to putting the primary key as the last column in a compound index; MySQL puts the equivalent on every index. **In MyISAM** you should put the PK there if your query needs it. Compound indexes that start with the primary key, or otherwise contain it, are still potentially useful.

A collection of single-column indexes cannot fulfill the same purpose as a well-chosen compound index. Having lots of indexes increases the chance that the query planner will find a useful one for a given query. But covering indexes designed for your queries can radically speed things up.

The space consumed by indexes is very roughly proportional to the amount of data they contain. Hard drive space is astonishingly cheap these days.

**In your Sql Fiddle** it's clear you should change the indexing on your `units` table. Get rid of the single-column index on `external_system_id` and replace it with this compound index.

```
INDEX `units_joindex` (`external_system_id`, `building_id`)
```

Like so: (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e5ffd/2/0). Be aware that `EXPLAIN` results, and the query plans, depend heavily on the contents and number of rows in the tables as well as the indexes.  Queries like yours necessarily must pull a whole table, so you won't see much index exploitation there.

Comment: @Ollie_Jones - thanks for the link. " Be aware that this will consume more space and that your inserts will slow down" - Do you know how much "space" is used by adding covering indexes? Is it "safer" to use multiple single indexes vs combined indexes? Currently the tables use single indexes.

Comment: also, since id is a PK already, it shouldn't be included in combined indexes or should it?

Comment: Please see my edits. Do take the time to read Use the Index Luke.